# Maximizing $\mbox{Tr}(MX)$ over $X \succeq 0$ with diagonal entries at most $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Does the following optimization problem have an analytic solution?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \mbox{Tr}(MX)\\ \text{subject to} & X_{ii} \leq 1 \quad \forall i = 1, \dots, n\\ & X \succeq 0\end{array}$$

where positive semidefinite matrix $M$ is given.

Comment: It looks like it might be the Frobenius norm of $M$.

Comment: I don't think so. That would be true if $\|X\|_F\leq 1$, not $X_{ii}\leq 1$.

Comment: @Michael Grant Rather, I mean the Frobenius norm of $M$ squared. (It is certainly at least this)

Comment: I definitely don't see that! But hey I don't have an answer, either, yet ;-)

Comment: Yes, this is just a conjecture for now.

Comment: Also @MichaelGrant you may assume $M$ is PSD. I just realized I'd made a mistake in transcribing the problem I am actually wanting to solve.

Comment: I'm playing with the dual problem and I think I have this: the answer is given by $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(S) \\ \text{subject to} & S \succeq M \\ & S ~\text{diagonal} \end{array}$$This is basically the dual of your problem, and it might help you or others come up with an answer. If $M$ were not PSD, you'd have to add an $S\succeq 0$ constraint, too.

Comment: @MichaelGrant doesn't this mean my conjecture is correct?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I see no reason to believe that the trace of $S$ would be equal to the Frobenius norm or its square. For instance, if $M$ is diagonal, then it would equal the trace of $M$, and that is neither.

Comment: Isn't this problem equivalent to minimizing $c^T \mathbf{1}$ subject to $c \succeq \lambda(M)$?

Comment: (above, by $\lambda(M)$, I mean the vector of eigenvalues of $M$, in decreasing order, if you like)

Comment: I do not believe that to be the case (except when $M$ is diagonal); but even if it were, the sum of the eigenvalues is not the Frobenius norm, or its square.

Comment: You're right. It would the Frobenius norm squared of its square root, however.

Comment: Wait, also doesn't $S \succeq M$ imply $\lambda_i(S) \geq \lambda_i(M)$ for all $i$? And $S = \mathbf{diag}(\lambda_i(S))$

Comment: Again, only in the diagonal case (and it would be the square of the Frobenius norm of the square root). Not a particularly useful result, and it isn't yet proven for the non-diagonal case.

Comment: Ah I see. It would be true, if for example, $S$ and $M$ were simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: My dual problem looks similar in structure the educational testing problem, which looks for the largest diagonal matrix that can be subtracted from a matrix while keeping it positive semidefinite. That one has no analytic solution, either.

Comment: @MichaelGrant can you explain how you got your dual. For some reason when I dualized I am getting $S \preceq M$.

Comment: Oh I see. When you do the conic lagrangian you introduce the term $\langle Z, X\rangle$, not -$\langle  Z, X \rangle$.